# get part of a string which contains given substring

Tags: regex, string, bash

In bash I have a string and would like to get the part (separator being white space characters) that contains a certain substring. Like I have

```
LIST="some string with a substring you want to match"
```

and my substring is "ubst". I'd like to get the string "substring" returned. (In case of multiple matches it should return the first substring that matches.)

The parts of the string are compiler flags. So they can contain special characters (but no white space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
str="some string with a substring you want to match"
awk -v s='ubst' -v RS=' ' '$0 ~ s' <<< "$str"
substring
```

- `-v RS=' '` will set record separator as space thus breaking each space separated word into individual record.
- `$0 ~ s` will return the word when word matched your given search term

**PS:** If you want to print only the first match use:

```
awk -v s='ubst' -v RS=' ' '$0 ~ s{print; exit}' <<< "$str"
```

---

Just for academic exercise if one wants single grep then use this PCRE regex:

```
grep -oP '^(?:(?!\w*ubst).)*\K\w*ubst\w*' <<< "$str"
```

Comment: Just for academic exercise if one wants single `grep` then use: `grep -oP '^(?:(?!\w*ubst).)*\K\w*ubst\w*' <<< "$str"`

Answer (score 2):

Using only grep with the -o and head:

```
echo "${LIST}" | grep -oe '[^ ]*ubst[^ ]*' | head -n 1
```

Comment: You get 2 hits when LIST="substring1 substring2"

Comment: @WalterA You get only one hit because of the `-m 1`, which only returns the first match.

Comment: -M 1 returns only hits from the first line, and you have two hits on the first line. Try it!

Comment: Who said anything about "-M"?

Comment: Thanks @WalterA for pointing out the flaw with `-m 1`. I edited my answer to match the questions desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Using tr and grep

```
echo "${LIST}" | tr " " "\n" | grep -m1 ubst
```

Comment: When LIST start with a `-`, use `echo "notmatching ${LIST}"`

Comment: ... Or switch to `printf` which was devised as an alternative without the various issues with `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

line="some string with a substring you want to match"

print_inarray ()
{ 
    local n=$1 h
    shift
    for h in "$@";do
        if [[ $h = *"$n"* ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "$h"
            return
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

# Read the line into an array.
read -ra arr <<< "$line"
# Find a substring of a word in array and print the complete word.
print_inarray "ubst" "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: As a side not, and regarding the variable "$LIST" that you have declared:
By convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the built-in *regex* operator for the `[[` conditional:

```
str="some string with a substring you want to match"
a=( $(echo "$str") )
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
    [[ "$i" =~ "ubst" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```

You can also use the POSIX compliant `expr string : regex` expression as well:

```
[ $(expr "$i" : ".*ubst.*") -gt 0 ] && printf "%s\n" "$i"
```

Comment: If as the OP indicates the real data contains shell metacharacters, interpolating it unquoted is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS='[ \t]'  '!/ubst/{next}1'
```

#### Description:

As you stated that

> (separator being white space characters)

The string could be broken into records by that, then just match the record that contain `ubst`.

```
LIST="some string with a substring you want to match"

echo "$LIST" | awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]'  '!/ubst/{next}1'
```

Well, really, if the record does not match `ubst` goes to the `next` record.
Any record that **is** matched falls to the default `1` which means `print`.